# Gmail Drafts: Not able to delete the attachment

Tags: python, email, gmail, gmail-api

I am generating Draft email from Python and attaching the files. (I am using the code from [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending))

**Problem:** If I delete the attachment from the draft email and send it, the attachment get's sent.

**Step 1:** Drafts generated by Python script
[image: Drafts generated by Python script]

**Step 2:** Removed the attachment by manually deleting it.
[image]

**Step 3:** This is the received email, (the attachment is present)
[image]

Not sure how to fix it. Is this a bug or Gmail behaving as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you thoroughly read the documentation about [Working with Drafts](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts)

> Drafts represent unsent messages with the `DRAFT` system label applied.
>   ***The message contained within the draft cannot be edited once created,
>   but it can be replaced***. In this sense, the [draft resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts) is simply a
>   container that provides a stable ID because the underlying message IDs
>   change every time the message is replaced.

That could be the reason.